# Can't pause python process using debug

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

I have a python script which starts multiple sub processes using these lines :

```
for elm in elements:
    t = multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_process,args=[elm])
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
   t.join()
```

Sometimes, for some reason the thread halts and the script never finishes.
I'm trying to use VSCode debugger to find the problem and check where in the thread itself it stuck but I'm having issues pausing these sub processes because when I click the pause in the debugger window:
[image]

It will pause the main thread and some other threads that are running properly but it won't pause the stuck sub process.
Even when I try to pause the threads manually one by one using the Call Stack window, I can still pause only the working threads and not the stuck one.
[image]

Please help me figure this thing, It's a hard thing because the thing that makes the process stuck doesn't always happen so it makes it very hard to debug.

Comment: Could you post the error message as if it's running that many subprocesses then it could be a hardware limitation which would explain why you'd be struggling to pause a subprocess

Comment: @SophieOH there is no error message, that's the problem. But I started to log EVERY line and I saw that it maybe stuck when I try to acquire a semaphore.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to clearly distinguish between threads and processes? Your description starts with having a problem about a subprocess, but then says dir example "I can still pause only the *working threads and not the stuck one*." implying your issue is with a thread instead. It would also be helpful to (roughly) know what the processes/threads are doing - for example, do they run computations with compiled code (say numpy) or are they pure Python, do they rely on external resources such as distributed file systems or network?

Comment: Unfortunately, answering your question doesn't solve your problem.  That would require access to more of your code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, those are subprocesses, not threads.  It's important to understand
the difference, although it doesn't answer your question.

Second, a pause (manual break) in the Python debugger will break in Python code.
It *won't* break in the machine code below that executes the Python, or in the machine
code below that performing the OS services the Python code is asking for.

If you execute a pause, the pause will occur in the Python code above
the machine code when (and if) the machine code returns to the Python interpreter loop.

Given a complete example:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

elements = ["one", "two", "three"]

def sub_process(gs, elm):
    gs.acquire()
    print("sleep", elm)
    time.sleep(60)
    print("awake", elm);
    gs.release()

def test():
    gs = multiprocessing.Semaphore()

    subprocs = []

    for elm in elements:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_process,args=[gs, elm])
        subprocs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in subprocs:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

The first subprocess will grab the semaphore and sleep for a minute,
and the second and third subprocesses will wait inside `gs.acquire()` until they
can move forward.  A pause will not break into the debugger until the
subprocess returns from the acquire, because acquire is below the Python code.

It sounds like you have an idea where the process is getting stuck,
but you don't know why.  You need to determine what questions
you are trying to answer.  For example:

(Assuming) one of the processess is stuck in acquire.  That means one of the other
processess didn't release the semaphore.  What code in which process is
acquiring a semaphore and not releasing it?

Looking at the semaphore object itself might tell you which subprocess is holding it,
but this is a tangent: can you use the debugger to inspect the semaphore
and determine who is holding it?  For example, using a machine level debugger in windows,
if these were threads and a critical section, it's possible to look at the critical section
and see which thread is still holding it.  I don't know if this could be
done using processes and semaphores on your chosen platform.

Which debuggers you have access to depend on the platform you're running on.

In summary:

- You can't break the Python debugger in machine code
- You can run the Python interpreter in a machine code debugger, but this
  won't show you the Python code at all, which make life interesting.
  This *can* be helpful if you have an idea what you're looking for -
  for example, you might be able to tell that you're stuck waiting for a semaphore.
- Running a machine code debugger becomes more difficult when you're running
  sub-processes, because you need to know which sub-process you're interested
  in, and attach to that one.  This becomes simpler if you're using a single
  process and multiple threads instead, since there's only one process to deal with.

"You can't get there from here, you have to go someplace else first."

You'll need to take a closer look at your code and figure out how
to answer the questions you need to answer using other means.

Comment: To find out which subprocess is holding the semaphore or lock, you can just add a debug print into the beginning of the critical section - the last printed (`flush=True`) line with subprocess identifier should correspond to the stuck one.

Answer (score -1):

It's just an idea, Why not to set a `timeout` on your sub processes and terminate it?

```py
TIMEOUT = 60

for elm in elements:
    t = multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_process,args=[elm])
    t.daemon = True
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    t.join(TIMEOUT)

for t in threads:
   t.join()
```