# Python BoundedSemaphore Acquire and then stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, semaphore

While trying to investigate this issue : [Can't pause python process using debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75161513/cant-pause-python-process-using-debug) I was trying to figure out what makes the sub process stuck so I ended up logging every line to a file and I encountered a weird situation where the sub process stuck right after it acquires the semaphore from the BoundedSemaphore.

This is the code:

```
my_queue = queue.Queue()
my_semaphore = BoundedSemaphore(10)

def execute_function(obj):
    log('execute function started')
    do the thing...

def start_function(obj, my_semaphore):
    log('start_function started')
    my_semaphore.acquire()
    log('sema acquired')
    execute_function(obj)
    log('function executed')
    my_semaphore.release()
    log('sema released')
 

for object in objects:
    my_queue.put(object)
    
while not my_queue.empty():
    obj=my_queue.get()
    thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_function,args=[obj,my_semaphore])
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

My queue include 1000-2000 records and my execute_function function can run 2000 times with no issues and sometimes it just stuck after some runs.
While I wasn't able to see exactly where it stopped because the issue I described here [Can't pause python process using debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75161513/cant-pause-python-process-using-debug) I logged every line and what I saw in the log of the process that stopped is that the last line it stopped in is 'sema acquired' meaning it successfully acquired the sema but for some reason didn't continue

Comment: because it is `doing the thing...`, it was probably suspended by the OS on some blocking action, also python buffers stdout so you may not see a few lines.

Comment: @AhmedAEK It's not doing the thing... because log('execute function started') wasn't fired